# cv2 - Load grayscale Image as Numpy Array from Variable

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, jupyter-notebook, computer-vision

I have a 2D numpy array that contains my grayscale image (8bit per pixel). I now want to load it into cv2 and resize it to a fixed width and height. But when I load the numpy array I get the following error: `OpenCV(4.5.2) (...) error: (-215:Assertion failed) buf.checkVector(1, CV_8U) > 0 in function 'cv::imdecode_'`

My code:

```
np_img = np.fromfile(path, dtype='uint8')
np_img = np_img.reshape(height,width)
img = cv2.imdecode(np_img,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

Comment: What happens if you reshape the image like this `np_img = np_img.reshape(height,width,1)`?

Comment: No need for `cv2.imdecode` here. If you already have an `uint8` NumPy array, you can use it directly in any OpenCV function.